# Flutter Floating action button error! Trying to create a row of button with a responsive touch effect

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-animation, flutter-web, flutter-test

My Code:

```
bool _isClicked = false;

@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
    body: Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 3.0),
      child: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: _isClicked ? Colors.orange[300] : Colors.white,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
        ),
        child: FlatButton(
          splashColor: Colors.orange[300],
          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
          ),
          onPressed: () {
            setState(() {
              _isClicked = !_isClicked;
            });
          },
          child: Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
              horizontal: 20.0,
            ),
            child: Text(
              foodItem,
              style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 20.0,
                color: _isClicked ? Colors.white : Colors.grey[700],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
     ),
   );
```

Reality:

[image: one1]
[image: two2]

**Expectation:**

1. When I click one button, only that turns orange the rest stay white.
2. When I click it back again, it turns grey again just like the rest.

Comment: explain more, add the widget containing them code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you want to achieve some kind toggle behavior for the buttons. Though `ToggleBar` widget is good for this it is not flexible with it expectations about child widgets. So a `ButtonBar` widget would be helpful with some kind internal state about the buttons which are clicked. Here is a working solution which might help you. The same code is available as a codepen [here](https://codepen.io/abhilas-csc/pen/ExPxpJp).

**Approach**

1. Extracted your code for the button into a widget called `TButton` with parameters as follows

   - `isClicked` - a boolean flag to denote if the button is clicked.
   - `foodItem` - the text to be displayed on the button.
   - `onPressed` - a callback function to be called when the button is pressed.
2. In the parent widget `MyButtons` hold a list of `bool` indicating the status of click for each button.
3. `MyButtons` accepts a list of `foodItems`. Iterate this list and generate a list of `TButton` widget and pass it to the `ButtonBar` as children.

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

final Color darkBlue = Color.fromARGB(255, 18, 32, 47);

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(
          primarySwatch: Colors.blue, scaffoldBackgroundColor: darkBlue),
      home: Scaffold(
        body: MyButtons(foodItems: ['Pizza', 'Burger', 'Kebab']),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyButtons extends StatefulWidget {
  MyButtons({Key key, this.foodItems}) : super(key: key);

  final List<String> foodItems;

  @override
  _MyButtonsState createState() => _MyButtonsState();
}

class _MyButtonsState extends State<MyButtons> {
  List<bool> isSelected;

  @override
  initState() {
    super.initState();
    // initialize the selected buttons
    isSelected = List<bool>.generate(widget.foodItems.length, (index) => false);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      // just for aesthetics
      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 80.0),
      child: ButtonBar(        
        // use the alignment to positon the buttons in the screen horizontally
        alignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        // iterate over the foodItems and generate the buttons.
        children: widget.foodItems.asMap().entries.map((entry) {
          return TButton(
              isClicked: isSelected[entry.key],
              foodItem: entry.value,
              onPressed: () {
                setState(() {
                  isSelected[entry.key] = !isSelected[entry.key];
                });
              });
        }).toList(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class TButton extends StatelessWidget {
  final bool isClicked;
  final String foodItem;
  /// OnPressed is passed from the parent. This can be changed to handle it using any state management.
  final Function onPressed;

  TButton(
      {@required this.isClicked,
      @required this.foodItem,
      @required this.onPressed});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: isClicked ? Colors.orange[300] : Colors.white,
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
      ),
      child: FlatButton(
        splashColor: Colors.orange[300],
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
        ),
        onPressed: onPressed,
        child: Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
            horizontal: 20.0,
          ),
          child: Text(
            foodItem,
            style: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 20.0,
              color: isClicked ? Colors.white : Colors.grey[700],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Sir thank you, however, is there an easier approach to this, I didn't quite follow some parts.

Comment: Depends on which parts you couldn't follow. I am quite sure this is already a simpler approach. Maybe you could replace the `ButtonBar` with a `Row` widget and achieve a similar look.